# getting uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, laravel, axios

i'm newbie in react, and come here to ask for help, because a getting the error as describred in the question title, follows a snippet of the code.

```
interface Contact {
  FirstName: string;
  PhoneNumber: string;
  id: string;
  photo: string;
}

class Store{

  public contacts;
  public filterString = "";

  constructor() {
    makeObservable(this, {
      // contacts: observable,
      filterString: observable,
      addContact: action,
      removeContact: action,
      updateContact: action,
      updateFilter: action,
      contactCount: computed,
      filteredContacts: computed,
    });

    this.getData();
  }

  async getData(){
    const value = await api.get('');
    this.contacts = value.data;
  }

  
  get filteredContacts() {
    // FIlter
    let filtered = this.contacts.filter((contact) =>
    contact.FirstName.match(new RegExp(this.filterString, "i"))
    );
    
    // Sort
    filtered = filtered.sort((a, b) => (Number(a.id) < Number(b.id) ? 1 : -1));

    return filtered;
  }
}

export default new Store();
```

I'm looking for change the contacts variable to an object array of my API. Can someone can help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider checking that `value.data` in `getData()` is an array or an object that has a `filter()` method.

Comment: Did you check what kind of data your getData() function returns?

Comment: I've make a little change in getData() function like this ``async getData(){
    const value = await api.get('');
    return value.data;
  }`` and put a ``console.log(this.getData())`` in contructor method, in the browser's console i've got 'Promise {<pendding>}'.